# Seeking Harry Potter fanfiction story

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

The story takes place after the Battle of Hogwarts. A young girl's father was killed and Harry and Ginny first take her in as foster parents then adopting her. The three Potter children are also included in the story not sure if they have gone to Hogwarts yet. This girl I believe is a lot older than Albus Potter. I do not recall her name or anything else, but it was a good story.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? This may well not be enough.

Comment: No I do not recall anymore details.

Comment: Sounds interesting... Any idea where you may have read it (ie. "which fanfic-archives do you frequent")?

Comment: fanfiction.net and archive of own.

Comment: For this type of query, I recommend the [HPfanfiction](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Canon#J.K._Rowling.E2.80.99s_Wizarding_World_Canon_tiers) subreddit, who treat this sort of question daily.